# Dot Net Offer Remote Assistance

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop

I have been attempting to use the Unsolicited Offer Remote Assistance function built into windows within my application for months now with no success.

to be clear, this is exactly thesame functionality as msra /offerRA computername.
where a Expert can Offer remote assistance to the novice without the novice having to create a ticketstring manually.
As far as i am aware this is accomplished using DCOM to communicate information using RAserver and then MSRA takes over for the actual connection.
I have confirmed that i can use MSRA /OfferRA ComputerName so the functionlity is there.

I have tried many API/DLL's and i still cannot figure out how to offer remote assistence in OFFERRA

I have trie the following modules.
AxRDPCOMAPILib
RDPCOMAPILib
RAServerLib
RendezvousSessionLib

i have tried so many different variations of code its not possible to post them all up here. i need some help to know how to use the OfferRA functionality using Windows Remote Assistance.
I DO NOT want to crate a peer to peer application. i would like my application to connect to remote assistance on the client computer using the MSRA that is installed on their computer from Microsoft.

Any help would be appreciated.

Attempted Code1:

```
        AxRDPViewer Viewer = new AxRDPViewer();
        Viewer.BeginInit();
        Viewer.SuspendLayout();
        RemoteAssistanceWindow.Child = Viewer;
        Viewer.ResumeLayout();
        Viewer.EndInit();
        ((AxRDPViewer)RemoteAssistanceWindow.Child).Connect("DZ0006", "MySecretUsername", "MySecretPassword");
```

Results:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in AxRDPCOMAPILib.dll

The program '[4936] Enterprise.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[4936] Enterprise.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Update 2:

```
        RDPViewer Viewer = new RDPViewer();
        IMRequestRA Request = new IMRequestRA();
        Request.SetRendezvousSession(Viewer);
```

The thread 0x1c60 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

The program '[7520] Enterprise.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[7520] Enterprise.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 
'Access violation'.

Comment: i cannot seem to use OfferRA using the librarys. RAserverLib has a IIMOfferRA interface but i cant use it. nothing happens. no event logs and noting in the output window. just this The program '[6388] Enterprise.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6388] Enterprise.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 2):

Remote Assistance using the MSRA Exe and its arguments.

Here I have designed a class and a form,  and it gives you the following functionalities,

1. Offer Remote Assistance to a Machine
2. Ask for Remote Help. (Invite someone to help you)

Design A form with the following controls,

1. Textbox for taking the IP or Computer name to Connect
2. Button 1. To connect to the Remote Machine for offering Remote Assistance
3. Button 2. To Ask or invite someone to help.

Code Behind in the Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RemoteAssist
{
    public partial class FrmConnect : Form
    {
        public FrmConnect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

     private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoteConnect remoteConnect = new RemoteConnect();
            Boolean status = remoteConnect.StartRemoteAssistance(txtComputerName.Text.ToString(), true,false);
            if (status == false)
            {
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to Connect to the Remote Machine.Please try Again later.");
            }
        }

        private void BtnInvite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoteConnect remoteConnect = new RemoteConnect();
            Boolean status;
            status = remoteConnect.StartRemoteAssistance(txtComputerName.Text.ToString(), false, true);

            if (status == false)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to Establish Connection, Please try Again later.");
            }
        }

        private void FrmConnect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void txtComputerName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtComputerName.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        }             
    }
}
```

We have two buttons here and they are sending the Boolean variable to the class function for differentiating between offer Help and Asking for Help.

Code under the Class File : RemoteConnect

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RemoteAssist
{
    class RemoteConnect
    {
        public Boolean StartRemoteAssistance(String strMachinename, Boolean offerHelp, Boolean askForHelp)
        {            
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();                        

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;            
            startInfo.FileName = "msra.exe";

            // Offer Remote Assitance 
            if (offerHelp == true)
            {
                startInfo.Arguments = "/offerRA " + strMachinename;
            }

            //ASK for Remote Assistance
            if (askForHelp == true)
            {
                startInfo.Arguments = "novice";
            }

            try
            {
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error Occured while trying to Connect" + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just pasting code, your answer might be more useful if you explained how it solves the problem at hand.

Comment: This is a straight forward solution, which utilizes the MSRA arguments for providing Remote Assistance and Asking for Remote Help in one click. The code behind the Command buttons calls MSRA and passes two different arguments for Remote Assistance and Ask for Assistance functionalities.

Comment: Thank you. I see that they post was updated as well. BTW, It wasn't me that voted down. It is sad that many do that without leaving a comment why. It would be helpful to know why and learn from this.

Comment: No worries mate... dont Care much about the votes, just want to make sure that this will be useful for someone like us.